# Using Excel Solver in VB with no cell references?

Tags: vb6, excel, vba

I am writing some visual basic code to solve for a solution. In the end I want it to optimize the solution through iterative method which is exactly what the Excel solver does. However I need it in pure VB. The Excel solver relies on cell references which does not work for me :(

My problem has 6 parameters and 1 value to minimize.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you push your data to cells and then use solver? If you're loading the excel anyway...? Alternatively it sounds like you'd need to write your own "optimizing" solution - in which case probably abandon excel altogether...

Comment: Could you post the function you want to minimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the solver without cell references - you'll have to put the info into cells and then call it.